# Matrix Theory book Recommendations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently reading Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right". Can anyone recommend any good books on matrix theory at about the same level that might compliment it?

Comment: Believe it or not, Schaum's outline is great for supplemental reading.  Lots of worked out problems too.

Comment: Horn & Johnson's books contain a lot of information about matrices: [Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.ca/books?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [Topics in Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.ie/books?id=LeuNXB2bl5EC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Probably at a higher level, though.

Comment: Gilbert Strang's [book](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Linear-Algebra-Fourth-Edition/dp/0980232716/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386279523&sr=8-1&keywords=gilbert+strang+linear+algebra) is an amazing book

Comment: I don't know if there's a better book than Schaum's Outline for a first course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [*Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra*](http://www.matrixanalysis.com/) by Meyer.