# Good Linear Algebra Book Suggestion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can you recommend a good reference for learning linear algebra with an eventual goal of applying tools from matrix theory? I have Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and Horn&Johnson's Matrix Analysis books, but I am not sure whether to learn matrix theory, I should study linear algebra first; and if that is the case, whether Axler is the best to study.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See [this question and its answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra?rq=1)

Comment: See also [this question and its answers for good reference for studying matrix theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594657/matrix-theory-book-recommendations?rq=1)

Comment: For more suggestions regarding linear algebra texts, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804716/very-good-linear-algebra-book?rq=1)

Comment: Please search for reference material on a topic before posting here. You've asked questions, recently, for reference and recommendation for linear algebra (here), but also for "functional analysis" and for algebra, and all three questions were closed as duplicates.  I like helping folks with their questions, but not when I have to perform searches, because didn't, prior to posting.

Comment: You might also want to look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173441/book-suggestion-for-linear-algebra-2?rq=1) in which the asker is approaching the end of Strang's text, and looking for a follow-up (part 2) to Strang.  You'll find a few recommendations regarding matrix analysis.

Comment: Hello Aaron, in their preface, Horn and Johnson write "We assume background equivalent to a one-semester elementary linear algebra course and knowledge of rudimentary analytical concepts." However, they also include in their Chapter 0 a very brief treatment, often without proof, of a number of concepts not covered in all introductory linear algebra books. So if you see that many of these aren't covered in Axler's book, then it would be a good idea to edit your question to name specific topics you'd like addressed in your elementary book. Also have a look at Lang's *Linear Algebra*.

Comment: Thanks a lot user49640. @amWhy, I am aware that my questions might be possibly flagged as duplicate, but my questions are usually not what's a good book type of thing, it also has my background plus possible books that I have at my hand, while most of the other question are more general. This is why I've still asked.

Comment: You can't come to that conclusion **until you search similar posts**.  So your first step in looking for book recommendations is to search the many such recommendations in many such fields.  If you don't also read the answers to such question, which are often more focused, you're insincere to say your question is unique, or different..  Duplicates on this site need not match each other word for word, character for character. Only after searching similar questions, **and** the recommendations posted, should you ask yet another book recommendation for your more recent topic of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Introduction to Linear Algebra by Prof. Gilbert Strang. It's a masterpiece.
http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/

This book is very easy to read and understand with lots of examples and explanations.

This book really helped me understand what really a matrix is.

It helped me understand many machine learning algorithms such as Linear Regression, Minimization of a cost function, Principal Component Analysis, Singular Value Decomposition and much more.

So, I think this book can be a life saver for a Math or CS grad.

Comment: That's a helpful suggestion,  but it remains only a suggestion, and not an answer.  You essentially link to the book, and provide you opinion about the text, without explanation as to what makes it a good reference.  What is it about Strang's text that makes it better than most texts in introducing linear algebra? I agree that Strang's book is very good.  But what's lacking is any explanation about its attributes.

Comment: This book is very easy to read and understand with lots of examples and explanations. This book really helped me understand what really a matrix is. It helped me understand many machine learning algorithms such as Linear Regression, Minimization of a cost function, Principal Component Analysis, Singular Value Decomposition and much more, So, I think this book can be a life saver for a Math or CS grad.

Comment: I inserted your comment immediately above, so that it enriches your answer post.